# Dialog Flow Alexa Skill Json Generation

Tags: dialogflow-es, alexa-skills-kit

I am facing the issue while trying to generate the Json files for the Alexa from Dialog Flow.
Error is mentioned below.
`Referenced entity [meta.timer-atom] must be defined`